# Calculate base and coefficient for power curve through 3 non-linear points

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, numerical-methods, graphing-functions, computational-geometry

I have a formula that takes a 0-based bounded single dimensional input and transforms it to a specific power curve.

**EDIT**

This is single dimensional. There is no $y$. In the image, I'm showing how the $x$ input is transformed. The only way to show this is to simulate it in the $y$ dimension. Technically, the graph should be shown stepped, but this is inconsequential to what I need.

If this isn't clear, then simply consider the curve to be a straight line with 3 points.

Looking at the image within the context of the *input*:

$k$ represents the number of buckets; this is logarithmic bucketing & I'm dividing A-C into $k$ logarithmic buckets; $k$ is predefined.
$A$ is always $0$ and is the lower bound.
$B$ maps to an output of 1, meaning the second bucket (0 is first); it is the beginning point of the second bucket; $B$ is predefined.
$C$ is the upper bound target, always +; $C$ is predefined.

[image: Power Curve with 3 Non-Linear Points]

The output $z$ is calculated as: $$z=\lfloor log_b(xR+1) \rfloor$$ where $$R=\frac{b^k-1}{C}$$

I need to determine $b$ based on $C$, $k$, and $B$. I worked out a recursive approximation algorithm, but I would prefer a formulaic solution.

**EXAMPLE**

$C=17987547480$
$k=128$
$B=0.000001$
$b=1.3280368123342627$
$R=328036.81233426905$

*The difficulty is that $b$ and $R$ need to be simultaneously solved.*

Comment: Why the downvote? Only useful with explanation.

Comment: $f(x)$ is not defined in the question, and $r$ is not in any of the formulas, only referred to in a sentence without having it related to other quantities. What is the use of the extra quantity $n$?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand the description. "$A$ is always zero...": Perhaps you mean that $A$ (a *point* in your diagram) always has $y$-value zero. "$B$ is $f(x)=1$ [...]; called $r$...": I'd *guess* you mean that $B$ is the point where the (unidentified) function $f$ has a $y$-value of $1$, and you're calling the corresponding $x$-value $r$; please confirm. "$C$ is [...]; called $t$ ...": Is $t$ the $x$-value or the $y$-value of point $C$? Also, as @coffeemath noted, there's no $r$ in your formulas; I *think* you intend the $x$ in your first equation to be $r$, but that's also a guess.

Comment: I hope my edits help clarify the question. $r=B$

Comment: The two displayed formulas contain neither $B$ nor $r$ (lower case). Also if $r=B$ why not give it a single name? One more thing: is $f(x)$ defined by use of the floor function? I ask because your graph is not a step function, and it is also not clear if the graph is supposed to be the graph of $f(x)$...

Comment: $r$ is part of the unknown formula that I need in order to find $b$ and $R$. Yes, I could scrap $r$ and call it $B$. The graph should be stepped, but I was merely trying to show it's curved. Maybe I should remove it.

Comment: Still not clear. All that's said about $B$ is the confusing statement "$B$ is $f(x)=1$." The equation $f(x)=1$ may have a solution $x=x_0$, and how can an equation be referred to as $B$? Even if $B$ were defined as the solution $x_0$ to $f(x)=1$, it would leave one to wonder how $B$ could be predefined, since it seems $x_0$ depends on $b$ and $R$.

Comment: Whatever the value of B, it results in x mapping to the second bucket (#1, #0 being first).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The curve $z=\log_b(xR+1)$ has $z(0)=0$ and $z(C)=k$ provided $R$ is defined as
$$R=\frac{b^k-1}{C}.\tag{1}$$
From a comment it appears you want $B$ to denote the value of $x$ at which $z(x)=1$, and since $z$ is defined as a log base $b$ this means that at $x=B$ the input of the log should be $b$ [since $\log_b(b)=1$]. This gives $BR+1=b$ or
$$R=\frac{b-1}{B}.\tag{2}$$
Now from your example and the post, $k$ is known (there are $k$ or $k+1$ buckets, depending on whether bucket $0$ counts). It also appears you want to set the value $B$ yourself, as the $x$ value at which the curve $z$ first reaches $1$, and that the value $C$ is also regarded as known. With $B,C$ taken as known, either formula determines $R$ provided only we can find $b.$ Equating the right sides of $(1)$ and $(2)$ and rearranging, we have
$$\frac{b^k-1}{b-1}=\frac{C}{B}.\tag{3}$$
For even moderately large $k$ this is really a polynomial equation for $b$ of large degree, so there seems little hope for a closed form solution giving $b$ as a formula in terms of $C,B.$ One could carry out the division on the left of $(3)$ and get the polynomial 
$$1+b+b^2+\cdots +b^{k-1},$$
or perhaps save some notation by rewriting $(3)$ as
$$b^k -(C/B)b+(1-C/B)=0.$$
Either way it remains a problem of solving a large degree polynomial equation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So basically, the bottom line is there isn't a straightforward formula. My current algorithm takes about 131 steps to get the result accurate to the maximum 64 bit floating point resolution, guaranteed.

Comment: @IanC Maybe Newton's method or something similar could solve the polynomial quickly to some accuracy. (I'm not up on numerical methods...)

Comment: Thanks. I had another problem that apparently also requires Newton's method to solve. I have a personal friend who's up on them. Time to speak to him. I appreciate your time & help.